# memcpy for create int[] from byte[]

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, memcpy

I have a byte array that stores an unsigned 16 bit number, and I want to use my personal memcpy() to create a function that will add zeros when creating an int array.

```
void* Mymem_cpy(void* dest, void* src, int n)
{
    if (dest == NULL) return NULL;
    char* char_dest = (char*)dest;
    char* char_src = (char*)src;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        char_dest[i] = char_src[i]; 
    }

    return dest;
}


unsigned char bytes[8]{ 179, 16, 0, 0, 0, 40, 92, 0, 0 };

int IntArray[2];
Mymem_cpy(&IntArray bytes, 8);
```

After that, the IntArray array will contain 2 numbers (4275, and 23592), which is correct.

The problem is that the original bytes array looks like this

```
unsigned char bytesInput[4]{ 179, 16, 40, 92 };
```

Without zeros.
Is it possible to rewrite the Mymem_cpy function so that it automatically sets zeros where I need them for this task?

Comment: Possible? Sure, but you will have to write the handling of that, which will make it very different from a regular `memcpy` (and therefore should probably not be called that way anymore)

Comment: `void* my_mem_cpy_fill_excess_with_zero(void* dest, size_t dest_byte_size, void* src, size_t src_byte_size)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just two indexes

```
void* Mymem_cpy(void* dest, void* src, int n)
{
    if (dest == NULL) return NULL;
    char* char_dest = (char*)dest;
    char* char_src = (char*)src;

    for (int s = 0, d = 0; s < n; s += 2, d += sizeof(int)) 
    {
        char_dest[d] = char_src[s];
        char_dest[d + 1] = char_src[s + 1];
        for (int j = 2; j < sizeof(int); ++j)
            char_dest[d + j] = 0;
    }

    return dest;
}
```

Alternatively use `std::memset` with zero at the function beginning instead of the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you, you're a very good person! 

Using memset will it be faster? I'm critically needing the speed of this because I'm working with high speed cameras and images that are working in a c# WPF application. I want to use C++ some functions to speed up the image pixel arrays.

Comment: Using memset likely makes the code faster - an optimizing compiler can parallelize the single loop after memset.

Comment: @ЕвгенийФедоров If you are on .Net Core, going the C++ function route is the wrong approach. C# gives you all the tools you need to write a high-performance functions doing this, even using SIMD.

Comment: @SebastianRedl can you show some examples?

Answer (score 1):

If arrays have same size and want to ignore values at odd index, it's:

```cpp
uint32_t*  expand_even_cpy( uint32_t* dest, const unit16_t* src, size_t nb ) {
    if ( dest == NULL ) return NULL;

    for ( int i = 0, j = 0 ; i < nb ; i++, j+=2 ) {
        dest[i] = src[j];
    }
    return  dest;
}

int main() {
    uint16_t  words[4]{ 4275, 9999, 23592, 9999 };
    unit32_t  IntArray[2];
    expand_even_cpy( IntArray, words, 2 );  // => 4275 23592
    // or
    unsigned char  bytes[8]{ 179, 16, 0, 0, 40, 92, 0, 0 };
    expand_even_cpy( IntArray, bytes, 2 );  // => 4275 23592
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
No, the arrays can be different each time.